# Find a file with certain filename and size in linux?

Tags: linux, command-line, centos

Is it possible to search for files with a certain filename and size in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the following command you can search for files with .log and size over 100k in the actual directory.

```
find ./ -type f -size +100k -name "*.log"
```

Comment: Wrap the argument to `-name` in quotes to avoid it being expanded by the shell if a file matching the wildcard exists in the current directory. Also, `find` searches according to the criteria _in the order they are given_, and the name lookup is the fastest, so make it a habit to put the `-name` directive before `-type` and other directives that requires `stat` calling on files. See the second example given in the `GNU find` manual for a reference.

Comment: Thx for the comment, i wrap the argument in quotes.